# What is the best way to handle common term which contains special chars, like C#, C++

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some documents contains c# or c++ in title which use standard analyzer.
When I query c# on title field, I got all c# and C++ documents, and c++ documents even have higher score than c# document. That makes sense, since both '#' and '++' are removed from token by standard analyzer.

What is the best way to handle this kind special terms? In my case specifically, I want c# documents got higher score than c++ documents when searching for "C#".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is approach you can use:

1. Introduce copy-field where you will have values with special characters. For that you'll need:

   - Introduce [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html) (`whitespace` tokenizer is important here - it will preserve your special characters):

     ```
     PUT my_index     
     {
        "settings":{
           "analysis":{
              "analyzer":{
                 "my_analyzer":{ 
                    "type":"custom",
                    "tokenizer":"whitespace",
                    "filter":[
                       "lowercase"
                    ]
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
     ```
   - Create [copy-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) (`_wcc` suffix will stand for 'with special characters'):

     ```
     PUT my_index
     {
       "mappings": {
         "my_type": {
           "properties": {
             "prog_lang": {
               "type": "text",
               "copy_to": "prog_lang_wcc",
               "analyzer": "standard"
             },
             "prog_lang_wcc": {
               "type": "text",
               "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
     ```
2. When issuing query itself you will combine query with boost against `prog_lang_wcc` field like this (it could be either multi-match or pure boolean + boost):

   ```
   GET /_search
   {
     "query": {
       "multi_match" : {
         "query" : "c#",
         "type": "match_phrase",
         "fields" : [ "prog_lang_wcc^3", "prog_lang" ] 
       }
     }
   }
   ```